# Re-indexing an array by matching value

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to manipulate the sorting order of an array. I would like to get the matching fruit - in this case the apple - as the third index on the array.

```
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'kiwi', 'color' => 'green');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'orange', 'color' => 'orange'); 
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'strawberry', 'color' => 'red'); 
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'lemon', 'color' => 'yellow');  

$i = 0;  

$array_inStock = array();  

foreach($array_fruit as $fruit)  
{  
    if($fruit['fruit'] == 'apple')  
    {  
        $array_inStock['3'] = array('fruit' => $fruit['fruit'], 'color' => $fruit['color']);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $array_inStock[$i] = array('fruit' => $fruit['fruit'], 'color' => $fruit['color']);  
    }  
    $i++;  
}  

asort($array_inStock);

print_r($array_inStock);
```

I don't understand what is going wrong here. Anybody an idea? Big regards.

Comment: So what is the result of current code?

Comment: Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => banana
            [color] => yellow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => kiwi
            [color] => green
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => orange
            [color] => orange
        )

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

although this is a lengthy way, but works perefect no matter where apple is currently

```
$array_stock =array();$i=0;
foreach($array_fruit as $k=>$v)
{
if($v['fruit'] =='apple')
    {
        $array_stock[3]=$v;
        if($k>3)
            array_push($array_stock,$array_fruit[3]);
        continue;
    }
if(array_key_exists($i,$array_stock))
{
    array_push($array_stock,$v);
}
else
{
    $array_stock[$i]=$v;
    $i++;
}
}

ksort($array_stock);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_stock);
echo "</pre>";
```

#### [DEMO](http://codepad.org/XJ39kp2H)

Comment: awesome, this solved the puzzle. Big thanks to all of you who have helped

Comment: @ian if `apple`s come always on top `[0]` or before [3]`` then u can remove `if($k>3)` condition

Answer (score 0):

Am I misreading this or do your lines

```
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow');
etc.
```

rewrite the contents of the array each time? Instead you want

```
$array_fruit[0] = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red');  
$array_fruit[1] = array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow');
etc.
```

Comment: No, the indexing adds up as your second example automatically

Comment: not necessary to assign index...it will automatically placed. read this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that going through the foreach loop has this events:

1. `$i = 0`, `array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red')` is processed and `$array_inStock['3'] = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red')` is created
2. `$i = 1`, `array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow')` is processed and `$array_inStock['1'] = array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow')` is created
3. `$i = 2`, `array('fruit' => 'kiwi', 'color' => 'green')` is processed and `$array_inStock['2'] = array('fruit' => 'kiwi', 'color' => 'green')` is created
4. `$i = 3` **!!!**, `array('fruit' => 'orange', 'color' => 'orange')` is processed and `$array_inStock['3'] = array('fruit' => 'orange', 'color' => 'orange')` is created that **OVERWRITES** the first processed `array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red')`...

What You should do instead:

```
foreach($array_fruit as $fruit) {  
    if($fruit['fruit'] == 'apple') {  
        $array_inStock[3] = $fruit;
    } else if($i != 3) {
        $array_inStock[$i] = $fruit;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This will end up with apple being the index 3...

Comment: When there are more fruits the result ends up being this: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => banana
            [color] => yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => kiwi
            [color] => green
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => lemon
            [color] => yellow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => orange
            [color] => orange
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => strawberry
            [color] => red
        )

)

Comment: so there will be no apple in the result

Comment: This is great, but now apple has an index of 4 instead of 3 (I have added a few more fruit to the first array in my post)

Comment: Hmm, OK, so apple shouldn't be last, but has an index 3? Why do You need this?

Comment: The matching fruit will be echoed to the screen as the 3rd result in the first row, so when I change the matching word to look for it will always end op the 3rd result and all the other results will go down (second row)

Comment: This works as a charm although it is now not matching towards apples but towards $i. So when I change apple to banana I will have another problem. Hope you'll understand

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but if You need to have some element at concrete index that cannot be done by sorting or ordering, this has to be hardcoded... I don't see any logic here that could be implemented as an algorithm... But OK, I changed the code once again slightly...check it...

Comment: This was how I ended up before creating the provided sample code. The problem now is that the code stopped running when it reaches the index 3. Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => apple
            [color] => red
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => banana
            [color] => yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => kiwi
            [color] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => orange
            [color] => orange
        )

)

Comment: And isn't this just because You have only 4 items in $fruit array? If so, the last index is 3. Try adding other items and the result array should be bigger... aaaaaaaahh, now I see it...put the $i++ after the end of `else if() {}`... This will evoke the first index to be 1 (not 0) but this shouldn't be a problem - should it? Or You can set `$i = -1;`

Comment: There are 6 items in the fruit array. When I put the $i++ on the right spot, the array index [5] is then missing. Look at the answer from diEcho. That solved the puzzle. Big thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, I gave him 1+. And I'm giving up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :::

---

```
$array_fruit = array();  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'apple', 'color' => 'red');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'kiwi', 'color' => 'green');  
$array_fruit[] = array('fruit' => 'orange', 'color' => 'orange');  

print_r($array_fruit);

$i = 0;  

$array_inStock = array();  

foreach($array_fruit as $fruit)  
{  
    if($fruit['fruit'] == 'apple')  
    {  
        $array_inStock['3'] = $fruit;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $array_inStock[$i] = $fruit;
        $i++;  
    }      
}  

asort($array_inStock);
print_r($array_inStock);
```

Comment: the result is: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => banana
            [color] => yellow
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => kiwi
            [color] => green
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => lemon
            [color] => yellow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => orange
            [color] => orange
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => strawberry
            [color] => red
        )

)  so there are no apples left